# Передача параметров HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, input, ввод

Есть первая страница, на ней два поля ввод и кнопка "Войти", как по нажатию кнопки перейти на другую страницу, и передать в её JavaScript, строки из полей?

Comment: 1. записать в куки, на второй странице считать. 2. записать в `localstorage` и так же само считать на другой странице

Answer (score 0):

Ну если эти два поля не логин и пароль, то можно передать прямо через адресную строку, например вот page1.html:

```
<form action="page2.html" method="get">
   <input name="value1">
   <input name="value2">
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Код для page2.html страницы:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const value1 = urlParams.get('value1');
const value2 = urlParams.get('value2');
```

Comment: А если логин и пароль?

Comment: Задуматься о серверной части

Comment: @КириллНикифоров то передавать в открытом виде их нельзя. Вопрос зачем передавать логин и пароль с помощью средств javascript и html?